# Same question different tag

Tags: discussion

I want to re-ask [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50581/how-to-disable-all-ios-notifications-temporarily), but for iOS 6 (existing question, based on date, is for iOS 5).

What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to simply copy all the text and see if it needs editing - if you want to give credit to the original poster, that is nice - so paraphrase things unless you want it to be verbatum and you quote the author. For good form you should link to the old question and explain why you feel iOS 6 is different than iOS 5.

Unless you have a reason to believe the notifications are different, we should generalize the old question by an edit to say explicitly it's for iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Comment: Did this help? Feel free to commend, edit your question or let us know if we hit or missed the mark on this answer.